# onsenui adding a custom image in the navigation title

Tags: onsen-ui

Would like to know how to set an image in the navigation bar instead of the title. I would still require the left hamburger menu icon though.

Can this be easily achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was done part of their documentation of "ons-toolbar-button"

See it here: 'http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/aHmGL'

Click on the Images selection under "Toolbar Variants" to see how it looks.

```
[1]: http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/aHmGL
```

Comment: see how it was done in the HTML panel from the link above.